# Saving custom attribute value for category in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have been trying to create an attribute for the categories in magento at the backend through programmatically. So, I followed steps in http://www.hesselbom.net/magento-custom-attributes-with-selectbox and it works perfectly and even I can able to save the selected values. Whereas, if I try creating a text box attribute, the values is not getting saved. Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Following is my code.

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_textfield', array(
'type' => 'varchar', 
'label' => 'Custom field', 
'input' => 'text', 
'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'visible' => TRUE,
'required' => FALSE,
'default' => ''
));

$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, 'custom_textfield');
```

I have also updated the version in the config file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with it work for me

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_textfield', array( 
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'Custom field ',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'        => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    ));
```

Comment: it display in category or have you check in db its entry?

Comment: Where and how to do it? Since I'm new to magento I'm not sure where to do that?

Comment: accept the answer if you find helpful @SaravananSampathkumar

Answer (score 0):

`$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_textfield', array(
    'group'                => 'General',
    'type'              => 'varchar',//can be int, varchar, decimal, text, datetime
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend_input'    => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Custom Field',
    'input'             => 'image', //text, textarea, select, file, image, multilselect
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => '[source model for attribute here]',//this is necessary for select and multilelect, for the rest leave it blank
    'global'             => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,//scope can be SCOPE_STORE or SCOPE_GLOBAL or SCOPE_WEBSITE
    'visible'           => true,
    'frontend_class'     => '',
    'required'          => false,//or true
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'position'            => 100,//any number will do
));`

This should do the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I found it. Below is the way to create and save attribute value at the admin panel.

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'length_waterline_custom', array(
'group'         => 'General',
'input'         => 'text',
'type'          => 'varchar',
'label'         => 'Length of Waterline',
'backend'       => '',
'visible'       => 1,
'required'      => false,
'user_defined'  => 1,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
```